# How to fix line breaks not working using '\n' from python function with .join()

Tags: python, function, printing, line, break

I have a function that when called loops through a dictionary object containing comments, and then should be displaying each one separated by a line.

I have searched through other topics on this I didn't find any one that answered for me.

I have tried '\n' '', but always get the text together.

```
def get_comment(stand):
    ''' Takes a comment code from the each of the comments
    field from inside the stand data and outputs
    a human readable text comment '''
    for _i in range(8):
        if stand:
            for _ in range(len(stand)):
                comments = []
                for _key, codes in stand.items():
                    comment = codes['carrier'] + ':' + \
                    codes['number'] + ' - ' + \
                    SamCode.objects.get(code=codes['dockingCode']).comment
                    comments.append(comment)

            return '\n'.join(comments)
```

This outputs

Eg.

```
AA:2776 - Manual start of system - ground AA:335 - Manual start of system - ground
```

whereas I need to to be

```
AA:2776 - Manual start of system - ground

AA:335 - Manual start of system - ground
```

Adding html template code for Django integration. Column.13 could have one comment or multiple as well as Column.14. Depending on the source of the comment.

```
   {% for column in performance.dailyDetails %}
    <td>{{ column.0 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.3 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.4 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.5 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.6 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.7 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.8 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.9 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.10 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.11 }}</td>
    <td>{{ column.12 }}</td>
    <td>{% if column.13 == None %}
        {% else %}
          {{ column.13 }}<br>
        {% endif %}
        {% if column.14 == None %}
        {% else %}
          {{ column.14 }}<br>
        {% endif %}</td>
```

Here is one of the JSON dictionaries that are being looped over. IT shows the \n in the comment already, but it is not line breaking when output to HTML:

```
{'partition': 'AA',
 'date': '04/14/2019',
 'sortingName': 'ORD.H16', 
 'stand': 'ORD.H16', 
 'acType': 'A321,A321/2,B737/8-WL', 
 'inbound': 7, 
 'outbound': 2, 
 'blockIn': 4, 
 'blockOff': 2, 
 'slaInbound': 4, 
 'slaOutbound': 2, 
 'samInternal': None, 
 'sdkTechnical': None, 
 'ground': 'AA:2776 - Manual start of system - ground\nAA:335 - Manual start of system - ground', 
 'pilot': 'AA:362 - UNK - pilot', 
 'tower': None, 
 'operational': None, 
 'infrastructure': None, 
 'interface': None}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input that would allow us to run your code.

Comment: Is this actually Django? Are you outputting this in a template? If so show that template. (And add the relevant tags.)

Comment: also, are you using windows notepad? Notepad needs newline and carriage return to print properly '\n\r' use notepad++ instead

Comment: Why do you have three nested loops? It seems like you really only need the innermost one.

Comment: I am working with a JSON API and the nested loops are to dig into the data from the larger data set.

Comment: Using VS Code and yes, using Django so I will post the template code.

Comment: But the outer loop at least is completely pointless; you iterate 8 times over a variable you don't use, you always return after the first successful iteration and you never modify any of the data within the loop, so if the first iteration fails so will the next seven.

Comment: I agree it seems pointless, but it was deemed needed at the time of writing it. There are 8 entries in each dictionary where the comments live. Some of them are single, some are multiple comments.  The get_comment() function operates over each of the dict's and then loops over each of the comment sections (always 8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely a matter of output. HTML ignores white space, including newlines; if you want data to appear in multiple lines you need to use HTML line break elements such as `<br>`.

There is a Django template filter that will translate newlines into HTML breaks: [`linebreaksbr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr).

```
{{ column.13|linebreaksbr }}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that all elements in comments list are string objects.

Regarding your question about adding a newline between comments, you got it almost right. If you print the returning value of the function, you will get the correct output

ex:

```
>>> x= '\n'.join(['1','2','3'])
>>> x
'1\n2\n3'
>>> print (x)
1
2
3
```